# Display sql server row without refreshing previous one(s) in vb.net web

Tags: sql, vb.net

i´m building a web program in vb.net where i want to display a sql server row in an asp:table or gridview and i want to look for another record (row) and display it in the same table without refreshing the previous row, then look for a new one and add it too and so on... So at the end i can send the information of every single row added to an invoice and sum the total. But every time i search for a new record, the row previously displayed dissapears, how can i look for a new one and add it to it instead of refreshing the table?.
I´m doing this by creating a dynamic table or dynamic rows so i can add a button to erase each row separately.
I have an UpdatePanel label to prevent postback so i now that is not the issue. Hope someone can help me.

```
x = ticket.Text
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Page.GetType, "Script", "showDisplay();", True)
    
    Using con As New SqlConnection("Server = 10.18.204.32;database=Fact;User ID=xx;Password = xxxx")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from Empresa where idEmpresa = '" + x + "'")               
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                Dim dt As New DataTable()
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.Connection = con
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                sda.Fill(dt)
                gvPreview.DataSource = dt
                gvPreview.DataBind()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

This is one of the codes i´ve tried because i saw GridView adds buttons by itself.

Comment: I think you are wanting to dsiplay the results in one datatable, and copy the results in to it from each subsequent database call/result. You can manually create a DataTable with the desired columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs on DataTable.Load

> If the DataTable already contains rows, the incoming data from the
> data source is merged with the existing rows.

This is helpful for what you want to do. However, due to post backs the DataTable needs to be in its own class.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim pk As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, pk) Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a number")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim dt = DataAccess.AddOneRecord(pk)
    gv.DataSource = dt
    gv.DataBind()
End Sub

Public Class DataAccess
    Public Shared dt As New DataTable
    Private Shared ConStr As String = My.Settings.CoffeeConnection
    Public Shared Function AddOneRecord(PK As Integer) As DataTable
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
                cmd As New SqlCommand("Select Name From Coffees Where ID = @PK;", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PK", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PK
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
        Return dt
    End Function
End Class
```

I used my own database for testing.
You could probably also use a Property stored in ViewState.

Comment: Thank you Mary, you just saved me. I have zero experience with vb.net and I´ve been struggling with this one for a while, it´s working perfectly now.

Comment: Hello, it´s me again. I have a huge problem with that part of the code and I really hope someone can help me.
The program is being tested right now by 2 people here at work, the issue I´m having is that when a user adds a ticket and the other user adds a different ticket just before that, the 2nd user gets the ticket the other one just added even though each of them have their own user and password and are working in 2 different computers so I don´t know why that is happening. I implemented the code exactly like Mary posted it and it works great but the issue comes when we have 2 users.

Comment: I really hope someone can help me, if you need more info I´ll be here.

Thank you in advance

Comment: @0Tommy The code above has a Select statement but you are having a problem with and Insert. Are you using an auto number field for the ID of the ticket? I suggest you ask a new question about the Inserts involved showing the code for the insert.

Comment: Hello Mary, is not an insert, what is happening is: The user looks for a number (ticket number) so she/he can retrieve it from the database and add it to a DataTable and then show it in GridView so when the 1st user looks for a ticket, it shows on his computer and then the 2nd user looks for a different one... the 2 tickets are added on the screen even though they are using different computers and each have their own username and password.

Comment: @0Tommy OK, The DataTable is Shared because it is used in a Shared function. Shared means it is common to all instances of the class. You can get rid of all the Shared keywords. Then each user will create an instance of the class `Dim datAcc As New DataAccess` and call the function `Dim dt = datAcc.AddOneRecord(SomeNumber)` Each user will then have there own copy of the data.

Comment: How can i show u my code? Because this is telling me it´s like 200 characters too long

Comment: @0Tommy Ask a new question with the current code and an explanation of your problem.

Comment: I did it exactly like you posted it a few months ago. The Public Class DataAccess part
And then i used: 
        Dim dtx As New DataTable
        Dim pk As String
        pk = txtNoTicket.Text
        dtx = DataAccess.AddOneRecord(pk)
All that on button click

Comment: I asked a new question, hope I did it right and hope you can find it, Thank you